# не могу открыть .doc-файл через COM-объект в php

Tags: php, iis, com, ms-word

из самого COM-объекта вываливается ошибка

> Source: Microsoft Word Description: Данная команда недоступна, так как
>   не открыт ни один документ. нет файла

пытаюсь открыть вот так:

```
$new_file3 = 'd:/EDO/tmp/1.doc';
$new_file4 = '../tmp/1.doc';

$error='';
$word = new COM("word.application") or $error.="Невозможно создать COM объект/n";

$word->visible = 0;

echo 'file_exist = '.file_exists($new_file4);
$word->Documents->Open($new_file4) or $error.='нет файла';
```

на папку (и на файл тоже) выданы полные права для всех и для группы IIS_IUSRS.

да, использую php 5.6 на IIS 7.5
windows web server 2008 R2

UAC отключил в винде
Что самое интересное, PHP видит файл в обоих вариантах ($new_file3 и $new_file4), а word - нет

Подскажите что можно сделать. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

проблема была в DCOM, точнее в его регистрации.
описание тут: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/11/12/microsoft-excel-or-microsoft-word-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in/